# Amazon S3 over VPN

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, vpn

Is it possible to establish VPN connectivity to Amazon S3 directly without utilizing Elastic cloud EC2?

Comment: S3 endpoint services introduce in 11 MAY 2015, which allow user to do this.   Render this question obsolete/outdated.

Answer (score 9):

Since S3 bucket names are globally unique and accessible over http using a unique url, it is not possible to isolate S3 at network level and it requires access control using Bucket Policies, IAM policies or Access control lists. You can also use Bucket Policies to whitelist Source Ip's that could access your buckets.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "IPAllow",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*",
      "Condition": {
         "IpAddress": {"aws:SourceIp": "54.240.143.0/24"},
         "NotIpAddress": {"aws:SourceIp": "54.240.143.188/32"} 
      } 
    } 
  ]
}
```

The Access Control system available in S3, enforces security in accessing S3. In addition the data in transit is encrypted using https and optionally you can also leverage encryption at rest for objects residing in S3 to further harden the security.

In addition there are multiple ways to establish connections to S3 based on the egress restrictions at the S3 access client locations (e.g. On-premise, VPC private/public subnet & etc.).

- Accessing S3 over the internet if there are no egress restrictions.
- Use [VPC Endpoints to S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-endpoints-s3.html) if you are accessing S3 from a AWS VPC.
- Direct Connect Connection from On Premise to AWS Data centers to access S3 over a dedicated, private network connection.

Unfortunately since S3 is not providing a feature for network segmentation, it is not possible to use a VPN connection to S3, restricting access at Network Level.

Comment: You cannot access S3 over a Direct Connection link.

Comment: @chirs Let me know your feedback on this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/directconnect/latest/UserGuide/WorkingWithVirtualInterfaces.html

Comment: To connect to S3 via Direct Connect, you need to use a Public VIF, which means the VPC you are connecting to must have an internet gateway - so all S3 traffic over the DX connection will be routed to S3 over the public internet.

Comment: @chris Isn't the connection happening from on-premise to S3 using Public VIF through direct connect (Still using the private line)?

Comment: Using s3:// or bucket.s3.amazonaws.com inside of a VPC with an S3 endpoint can resolve and route to it internally.  Trying to resolve the endpoint or connect to it outside the VPC needs to go thru the internet. Note also that you can't use the VPC DNS server outside the VPC.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Routing in a VPC is non-transitive.

[The relevant documentation:](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-endpoints.html)

*Endpoint connections cannot be extended out of a VPC. Resources on the other side of a VPN connection, a VPC peering connection, an AWS Direct Connect connection, or a ClassicLink connection in your VPC cannot use the endpoint to communicate with resources in the endpoint service.*

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.  Amazon Virtual Private Cloud seems like it can do that, but the docs always mention connecting to EC2 instances.

Answer (score 0):

Add one CIDR `52.192.0.0/11`(amazon CIDR) into VPN route and whitelist your VPN public IP into S3 bucket policy. S3 endpoint changes IPs frequently.

Comment: what does this do...